# Tweets of articles from links get a generic image

Tags: media, social-network

When I tweet the URL of an article on my Drupal 7 site, I get the correct summary, but the associated image is a generic icon -- not the image associated with the article. I've been trying to fix this via the Twitter Card and Metatag module in admin, but it's not going anywhere. Has anyone encountered and fixed this?

[image: Example of recent tweet with generic image]

Comment: Sometimes it just doesn't work for an hour then works again. But check your page headers to make sure the correct image URL is referenced.